# Creating Menus Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, menu

I'm started learning shell scripting, and I'm trying to figure out a way to add an option that returns the user back to the menu.
for example:

```
5) echo "Return to the menu"
   echo "Return back to the menu? ";;
```

Hear is the script on hand:

```
echo "1. I'm number one"
echo "2. I'm number two"
echo "3. I'm number three"

echo "4. Exit from menu "

echo -n "Enter one the following numbers:"

while :
do

read choice

case $choice in

  1)  echo "You have selected the number one"
      echo "Selected number is one";;

  2)  echo "You have selected the number two"
      echo "Selected number is two";;

  3)  echo "You have selected the number three"
      echo "Selected number is three";;    

  4)  echo "Exiting after the information have been received by both devices" # Referring to the TCP/IP protocol. The information has to be established by both client and device to act like a server before data is sent. Ok I'm showing of here :)
      exit;


  
esac
  echo -n "Enter one of the four options"
done # Sorry if there are errors in the this code, I wrote it on the fly :)
```

Comment: It would help to explain what your code currently does and how you want the output to be different. Should options 1-3 exit the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `select` to create a menu

```
#! /bin/bash

opts=( "I'm number one" "I'm number two" "I'm number three" "Exit from menu" )
PS3="Enter one the following numbers:"
select o in "${opts[@]}"
do
    case "$REPLY" in
        1)  echo "You have selected the number one: $o"
            echo "Selected number is one";;

        2)  echo "You have selected the number two: $o"
            echo "Selected number is two";;

        3)  echo "You have selected the number three: $o"
            echo "Selected number is three";;    

        4)  echo "Exiting after the information have been received by both devices" # Referring to the TCP/IP protocol. The information has to be established by both client and device to act like a server before data is sent. Ok I'm showing of here :)
            exit;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: It works only on Bash, I'm trying to it on #!/bin/sh !

Comment: You tagged the question `bash`

Comment: @Jada Have a look at what a shebang is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix).   /bin/sh often maps to the environment's default interpreter, which may or may not be what you want. Using the interpreter by name ensures the correct interpreter is used and can prevent some weird behavior if one environment defaults to a different interpreter.

Comment: @willpnw No problem. Thanks. But i usually run scripts like this `python3 myscript.py` or `sh myscript.sh`

Comment: Using shebang is much easier, you type less and also let's you invoke the script as `myscript` (getting rid of extensions that are useless) and not having to care about the interpreter or even if you decided to replace `myscript` by a native executable later on.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR ;) Put the usage in it's own function and call that when you want

I'd do something like this(shortened for brevity)

```
#!/bin/bash

printUsage() {
    echo "Enter one the following options:"
    echo "1: do 1 stuff"
    echo "x: exit"
    # add more as necessary
}

printUsage
while true; do
    read choice
    case $choice in
        1)
            echo "You have selected the number one"
            break
            ;;
        x)
            echo "k thx bye"
            exit
            ;;
        *)
            echo ""
            echo "Invalid option: $choice"
            echo ""
            printUsage
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "Doing $choice stuff"
```

Answer (score -1):

To add a return to menu feature, try this:
Add a variable accessMenu, set it to true, and update the while loop condition as so, and set accessMenu to false first thing in the loop...

```
accessMenu=true
while [[ $accessMenu -eq true ]]; do
    accessMenu=false
    ... (code)
done
```

Lastly, in the case that you want to enable returning to the menu, set the variable to true, and it will pass the condition in the while loop to run again.